# python tkinter cannot assign stringvar() set

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to create module based tkinter classes. I want to be able `var_text` variable to be able to print on `Label` text given to it.

```
from tkinter import *

class Maincl(Tk):
    def __init__(self,xwidth,yheight):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry(f'{xwidth}x{yheight}')
        self.var_text=StringVar()
        Labelcl(self,'darkblue',30,3).pack()
        Labelcl(self, 'white', 30, 3,self.var_text.set('hello tkinter')).pack()
        self.mainloop()

class Labelcl(Label):
    def __init__(self,master,bg_color,width,height,text_variable=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.configure(bg=bg_color,width=width,height=height,textvariable=text_variable)

app=Maincl('500','300')
```

But as of matter, for testing purpose I assigned(set) to `var_text` to "hello tkinter" but cannot see text when code is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the initial value when creating the `StringVar`:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Maincl(Tk):
    def __init__(self,xwidth,yheight):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry(f'{xwidth}x{yheight}')
        # set initial value using `value` option
        self.var_text=StringVar(value='hello tkinter')
        Labelcl(self,'darkblue',30,3).pack()
        # need to pass the variable reference
        Labelcl(self, 'white', 30, 3, self.var_text).pack()
        self.mainloop()

class Labelcl(Label):
    def __init__(self,master,bg_color,width,height,text_variable=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.configure(bg=bg_color,width=width,height=height,textvariable=text_variable)

app=Maincl('500','300')
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Because when you run the script it shows. But when I import module and run, window and labels are shown but not the text. What can be reason?

Comment: @xlmaster If you import this from other script, there may be more than one instance of `Tk()` which may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: @xlmaster add `master=self` inside the `StringVar(...)`

Answer (score 2):

`set()` on any `tkinter` variable will not return anything. So, `text_variable` is always `None` as `self.var_text.set('hello tkinter')` will return `None`.

```py
self.var_text.set('hello tkinter')
Labelcl(self, 'white', 30, 3,self.var_text).pack()
```

Here, it will pass the `StringVar` instance itself.

Comment: but you did not assign `StringVar()`. It does not show on my pC

Comment: @xlmaster In your code, you have specified `self.var_text` as `StringVar`.